# Python script that rectify's a given word in an .rtf file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python currently studying on it. I have a syntax like this:

```
def main():
#with auto \1 & \2 on replacement
search_replace_mixed = {'eousisienl':'consistent'}
#no auto variable on replacement
search_replace_exact = {'eousisienl':'consistent'}
```

which would rectify a misspelled word and i do not know what's next. My source document is .RTF and I wanted a python script that rectifies a word from the above syntax. Or if you have better ways to do it. Can you help me?

Comment: Is your question how to search through an rtf file and replace 'eousisienl' with 'consistent'?

Comment: @Daniel Yes sir sorry for my english..

Comment: @Lucas See if this answers your question: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace

Comment: @Daniel I stumbled onto that page but how can i write a decent code? Much easier to learn if someone would help. The idea is changing word/s in an .rtf document using python script because i have a lot of .rtf files

Comment: Do you know the exact words you are trying to replace?

Comment: Yes. I will send it to you i can't post it here limited characters.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways you can go about this. If you are just trying to switch a set of misspelled words you know are going to be misspelled you could hack together something like this:

```
filename = 'words.rtf'

search_replace_exact = {'eousisienl': 'consistent'}

with open(filename, 'r+') as file:

    text = file.read().split(' ')

    for index, word in enumerate(text):
        if word in search_replace_exact:
            text[index] = search_replace_exact[word]

    corrected_text = ''

    for element in text:
        corrected_text += element + ' '

    file.seek(0)
    file.truncate()
    file.write(corrected_text)
```

This will search through your RTF document and replace anything specifically outlined in your `serach_replace_exact` dictionary.

Comment: i'll test this tonight i am in class. I already have a script for mispelled words but the only thing it will rectify is .XML Daniel, i need this so bad if you can provide me with your email i will send my sript to you.